# Laravel 419 csrf token mismatch error,post data error,vhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I tried to add csrf using ajax,csrf token mismatch error

```
`$.ajax({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}});`
```

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

tried `@csrf` in form
`{{ csrf_field() }}`

[Web img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTexP.png)

[Cookie img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2vm0.png)

My laravel version is Laravel Framework 6.20.44

I wasted so many days on this so posted here,VerifyCsrfToken.php commented but that is not a secure way as well, after getting logged in, other csrf token and data tables ajax and other pages also not working.

using localhost:8000 these all functionality working.

using web.test vertualhost/linux its not working

is their any configuration i have to do?????from apache side

my .env has APP_KEY=base64:d81S8S.........key

Comment: did you set the key in your .env, if not run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: yes it already has

Answer (score 0):

In Your case there are no ajax request.

Inside form you need to add `@csrf` like this.

```
<form action="/foo" method="post">
   @csrf
   // etc...
</form>
```

Comment: Can you check Are you have  <meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> in your html part? It should be inside <head> tag

Comment: It is very strange